# Shell command to put recent line of output onto current command line

Tags: shell, command-line, command-history, output

Shells have a useful feature where pressing the keyboard UP arrow replaces the contents of the current command line with the previous **command** that was entered. (And if you do it again, the command before that, and so on.)

I would like a similar feature, where pressing (some other button) replaces the contents of the current command line with the **last line of output** from the previous command (and if you do it again, the previous line of output , and so on.)

Is there any shell that provides a feature like this?

The motivation is that you often want to run a command, and then run another command with part of the previous commands's output as input. (No, I don't want to do anything involving piping the output of one command into the next. I'm looking for an **interactive** experience, where you run the first command, **see** its output, and then get a line of that output into your next command, without having to reach for the mouse to do a clumsy copy-and-paste.)

Answer (score 3):

If you run your shell inside `screen`, you can use `screen`’s scrollback mode to achieve this. Using the default key bindings:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> enters scrollback mode;
- movement keys move up and down;
- <kbd>Y</kbd> copies the current line to the paste buffer and leaves scrollback mode;
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> pastes the buffer.

The documentation (run `man screen`) gives lots more detail and describes the other features of scrollback mode (including searches, partial copies etc.).

`tmux` no doubt has similar features.

Answer (score 0):

If I read that correctly, you want to take last line from the output of one command, and execute that as a new command.  Thus:

```
$ $( /path/to/command_generator | tail -n1 )
```

Or, if it's the contents of a file on disk:

```
$ $( tail -n1 /path/to/RUNME.txt )
```

If you want to edit this before execution, you can use `vipe`, which is a tool to edit the contents of pipelines in-flight:

```
$ $( /path/to/command_generator | vipe )
```

Comment: I did say I don't want to pipe the output of the first command into the next :)

Comment: `vipe` if not given an output to pipe into, will dump into standard output, which is then executed since that output is in a `$( )` "execute-me" subshell.

Comment: Ok, I kind of see how that approximates what I'd like. Still not quite there, though, as I still need to anticipate the fact that I'll need to run a follow-up command before running the first command. Sometimes, it's only after seeing the output of the first command, that I realize I want to run a second. So I'm looking for some "after the fact" access to the previous command's output. The "screen" feature from the other answer seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want `` `!!` `` to re-execute the previous command and use it's output inline, say looking for a file:

```
$ find . -name "myfile.txt"
./dir/files/myfile.txt
$ emacs `!!` &
emacs `find . -name "myfile.txt"` &
```

which would equate to:

```
$ emacs ./dir/files/myfile.txt &
```

Comment: Of course that is useful *per se* only if the previous command had only one line of output  (and you want to use it without modification).

Answer (score 0):

Bash can save the output of non-interactive commands, which you can then open in an editor using Ctrl-G and yank the field(s) you need into the current command line: https://asciinema.org/a/395092