# Do any commands exist that would let me copy the last line of the previous output to my clipboard?

Tags: bash, shell, osx, clipboard

I'm not sure if this should be here or over on AskDifferent, but I'm using a bash shell (iTerm) on MacOS. I sometimes have commands that produce additional commands that need to be copy/paste to the terminal.

An example of this is logging into the aws ecr:

`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region -eu-west-1`

This produces a multiline login hash that you need to copy and paste to the shell in order to successfully authenticate. Is there a way I can this and paste it from the keyboard or some command?

I've seen several ways to copy all of the output from a command to clipboard, but that's not exactly what I'm asking for. Specifically, I typically only want the last line in the output.

If nothing exists, I'd be perfectly happy with just setting up some sort of alias in my `.bashrc`

The recommended dupe answer expects you to use `screen` - I don't want to use `screen`

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/396540/86440) might be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you send to stdin of `xclip` will be stored in the clipboard (if you're running X). You can use `tail` to extract the last line of output:

```
for i in {1..10} ; do
    echo $i
done \
| tail -n1 | xclip
```

`10` is now in the clipboard.

Oops, I haven't noticed the `osx` tag. On OS X, a similar command seems to be `pbcopy`.